# How to dynamically show border on a div without changing its internal measures?

Tags: html, css

In below example I have two divs:

[image]

Both have the same content and almost the same style, except that the second div has one more style: 
    border: 1px solid black;

The problem is that this border is doing a resize of the internal content and I don't want this. I want to put a border on some divs on the page dynamically during the page load, but without chage any measures or changes in the content.

Has a way of doing this? I can use javascript if necessary, but a solution that only use css will be more apreciated.

Comment: provide your code please!!!

Comment: Isn't this:"I want to put a border on some divs on the page dynamically during the page load" allready implying JS?

Comment: you can use padding 1px to div without borer. and padding 0px to the border one.
this must be included on the event when border occurs.

Comment: @cytofu Not necessarily, imagine that I can do this changes by PHP code before send html to the client. But.. Okay, can be on javascript page load too.

Comment: Well, php isn't exactly on page load ;) php just generates the code that is sent to the client, when referring to "page load", it is usually understood as loading the page on the client side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of border use [outline](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_outline.asp)

```
div.border
{
    outline: 1px solid black;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/BCwhG/)

Comment: It's exactly what I wanted. Thank you @Matías.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use a transparent border, like: border: 1px solid transparent;
Then apply any other color you want.

Answer (score 2):

You can use transparent borders, then when you will apply border color the size will remain the same. Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uAuZg/)

**html**

```
<div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
div {
    border:2px solid transparent;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background:#eeeeee;
    margin:10px;
}
```

**js**

```
$("#red").on('click',function() {
    $("div").css("border","2px solid red");
});

$("#transparent").on('click',function() {
    $("div").css("border","2px solid transparent");
});
```

Comment: It's a good solution. But this way I would need add 2px border in all divs of the page, so I chose the @Matias answer. But anyway, thank you very much. =)

Answer (score 0):

#### You have 2 options.

- Use css : `1px solid transparent;` and
- Use css : `box-sizing:border-box;`